# How is it I can't access a module function from within a class from the same module in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm having some issues with the access rules of ruby.  At one point I thought that something like this worked:

```
module Foo
    def bar(x)
        puts "#{x}"
    end
    
    class Baz
        def initialize(x)
            bar(x)
        end
    end
end

Foo::Baz.new(3)
```

but somehow it no longer does.  I've tried to declare `bar` using `self.bar` and `Foo.bar`, but neither work.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inclusion of the module methods isn't "automatic", I think because it can lead to unexpected behavior.

You can try making them a class method as you mentioned, or including the module and getting access to the methods there:

```
module Foo
  class << self
    def bar(x)
      puts "#{s}" % x
    end

    def s
      "s1"
    end
  end

  def bar(x)
    puts "#{s}" % x
  end

  def s
    "s2"
  end
  
  class Baz
    include Foo
    
    def initialize(x)
      bar(x)
      Foo.bar(x)
    end
  end
end

Foo::Baz.new(3)
# s2
# s1
```

Comment: Interesting.  What is `class << self`?

Comment: Oh, the `puts` statement is wrong.  I mixed different string formatting styles. I've corrected it above.

Comment: `class << self` gives you access to `Foo`s metaclass. In this case you define the method `bar` and `s` within it, getting rid of the `self.` prefix which is implied by `class << self`.

Comment: But then, how do you access that class?  Or is that class being overlaid on `Baz`?

Comment: In this case as `Foo.bar(x)`.

Comment: Hmmm, seems that my original code worked.  Could be that the certain things aren't overwriting elements in the class/module, as I didn't reset the ruby interpreter.

Comment: Yes, it might totally be the case. But if you ask me, executing your code I get just a NoMethodError (`'initialize': undefined method 'bar' for #<Foo::Baz:0x0000558b4498a178> (NoMethodError)`).

Comment: So, `class Foo << self` is a metaclass of `Foo`, and `class Baz` is mixing that metaclass into itself?  Wow! So convoluted. :D

Comment: Hmmm.  Yeah.  Without the `include Foo`, it wouldn't work on [gdb](https://onlinegdb.com/rJcC6J4O_).  Could be that Sketchup 2017 has an old version of ruby that doesn't align with the latest build.  However, I don't think I need the metaclass.  That's just overkill.  Thx.

Comment: Yes, that might be possible, but it looks strange. If you inspect `Baz` methods, `bar` should be there, but where it's really coming from? Have never used Sketchup for this kind of things, so I might be missing an entire world.